# Fluid in moving glass simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I'm new to fluid simulations in blender.
I'm trying to make a simulation of chalice with a fluid dropped on the floor, 
but fluid reacts weird with chalice it escapes mesh of the obstacle in resolution 220 and when the chalice starts to fall (frame 20) fluid do not follow the chalice. Also fluid fly over surface. [Link to .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3a3iB0rCeZea18zb2pVakZqT0U/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

The 'normals' i.e. the direction of the faces on your chalice are inverted, or pointing the wrong way. The darkened shading of the chalice is indicative of this. This means that he fluid simulation will have trouble telling what the inside and the outside of your mesh is. On the left is your model with incorrect normals, and on the right, correct normals:

[image]

Enter edit mode for the chalice, select everything and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to 'Recalculate normals'.

As a side note, your fluid domain is very large. If you need it that large then that's fine, but if you don't, make sure your domain is as small as possible. Using a large domain will use a large amount of ram compared to a domain which is small and compact.

I would also recommend disabling 'Remove air bubbles' in the 'Fluid Boundary' panel for the domain object to stop the liquid appearing through the sides of the chalice.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answer this recalculate normals works and fluid behave way better but still it fly over surface and chalice.[Fluid over floor](http://i.imgur.com/an3rASN.png?1)  [Fluid over chalice](http://i.imgur.com/06xbfj6.png?1)  Also it is lagged when chalice starts to fall  [Lagged fluid](http://i.imgur.com/RKDklTY.png?1). Do you have some ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Is it possible you have made the domain too small now? Otherwise I'm afraid I don't know. It's very difficult to diagnose these issues as it takes a while to bake the fluid.